# How to use redux with react-plotly.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using [`react-plotly.js`](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/) and want to use redux to store the `layout` of my plot. I'm able to do it using react state, but the plot does not render when trying to do the same with redux.

I know that the redux state is updating correctly. I think my issue is related to the state management section in the link I provided above, but it's not clear to me why it does not work with redux state, but it works with react state.

Below is what you need to reproduce my project.

```
# Create new vite project
npm create vite@latest test-app --template react

# Dependencies from package.json
"dependencies": {
  "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
  "plotly.js": "^2.22.0",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-plotly.js": "^2.6.0",
  "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
  "react-resize-detector": "^9.1.0",
}
```

Directory structure and code:

```
├── src
│   ├── App.jsx
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── PlotReactState.jsx
│   │   ├── PlotReduxState.jsx
│   │   └── plotSlice.js
│   ├── main.jsx
│   └── store
│       └── store.js
```

**App.jsx**

```
import PlotReactState from "./components/PlotReactState";
import PlotReduxState from "./components/PlotReduxState";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Plot using react state</h4>
      <PlotReactState />
      <h4>Plot using redux state</h4>
      <PlotReduxState />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**components/PlotReactState.jsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Plot from "react-plotly.js";
import { useResizeDetector } from "react-resize-detector";

export default function PlotReactState() {
  const { width, ref } = useResizeDetector();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const [layout, setLayout] = useState({
    width: width,
    title: {
      text: title,
    },
    xaxis: {
      title: "",
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: "",
    },
    paper_bgcolor: "lightgrey",
    plot_bgcolor: "lightgrey",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setLayout((prevLayout) => ({ ...prevLayout, width: width }));
  }, [width]);

  // Modify one way
  useEffect(() => {
    setLayout((prevLayout) => ({ ...prevLayout, title: { text: title } }));
  }, [title]);

  // Modify another way
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setLayout((prevLayout) => ({ ...prevLayout, xaxis: { title: value } }));
  };

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Edit title"
        onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Edit x-axis title"
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event.target.value)}
      />
      <Plot layout={layout} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**components/PlotReduxState.jsx**

```
import Plot from "react-plotly.js";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useResizeDetector } from "react-resize-detector";
import { updateTitle, updateXLabel } from "./plotSlice";

export default function PlotReduxState() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { layout } = useSelector((state) => state.plot);
  const { width, ref } = useResizeDetector();

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Edit title"
        onChange={(event) => dispatch(updateTitle(event.target.value))}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Edit x-axis title"
        onChange={(event) => dispatch(updateXLabel(event.target.value))}
      />
      <Plot layout={layout} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**components/plotSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const baseLayout = {
  title: {
    text: "",
  },
  xaxis: {
    title: "",
  },
  paper_bgcolor: "lightgrey",
  plot_bgcolor: "lightgrey",
}

const plotSlice = createSlice({
  name: "plot",
  initialState: {
    layout: baseLayout,
  },
  reducers: {
    updateTitle: (state, {payload}) => {
      state.layout = {
        ...state.layout,
        title: {
          text: payload
        }
      }
    },
    updateXLabel: (state, {payload}) => {
      state.layout = {
        ...state.layout,
        xaxis: {
          title: payload
        }
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { updateTitle, updateXLabel } = plotSlice.actions;

export default plotSlice.reducer;
```

**store/store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import plotReducer from "../components/plotSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    plot: plotReducer
  },
});
```

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from './App'
import { store } from "./store/store";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `Plot` component from `react-plotly.js` doesn't work with `redux-toolkit` maintained state slices which disallow, or guard, against state mutations. I had noticed that the `PlotReactState` had some additional "state" properties that were never declared nor updated in your code.

```
export default function PlotReactState() {
  ...

  const [layout, setLayout] = useState({
    width: width,
    title: {
      text: title,
    },
    xaxis: {
      title: "",
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: "",
    },
    paper_bgcolor: "lightgrey",
    plot_bgcolor: "lightgrey",
  });

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

```
{
  paper_bgcolor: "lightgrey",
  plot_bgcolor: "lightgrey",
  title: { text: '' },
  width: 865,
  xaxis: {
    autorange: true, // <-- mutated state
    range: [-1, 6],  // <-- mutated state
    title: {
      text: ""
    },
  },
  yaxis: {
    autorange: true, // <-- mutated state
    range: [-1, 4],  // <-- mutated state
    title: { text: '' },
  },
}
```

To test this theory I created a "legacy" reducer function, e.g. a vanilla Javascript function that simply computes the state and doesn't protect it.

store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
// import plotReducer from "../components/plotSlice";

const baseLayout = {
  title: {
    text: ""
  },
  xaxis: {
    title: ""
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: ""
  },
  paper_bgcolor: "lightgrey",
  plot_bgcolor: "lightgrey"
};

const plotReducer = (state = { layout: baseLayout }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "plot/updateTitle":
      return {
        ...state,
        layout: {
          ...state.layout,
          title: {
            text: action.payload
          }
        }
      };

    case "plot/updateXLabel":
      return {
        ...state,
        layout: {
          ...state.layout,
          xaxis: {
            title: action.payload
          }
        }
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    plot: plotReducer
  }
});
```

Running your same code but with this legacy reducer function, the redux state is now also mutated and the additional values injected into state, but the plot renders.

[image]

Unfortunately `redux-toolkit` still does a mutation check so when you try to update the title there will be an invariant violation.

[image]

You can try configure the store to skip the immutability check. See [Immutability Middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/immutabilityMiddleware) for details.

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    plot: plotReducer
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      immutableCheck: {
        ignoredPaths: ["plot"]
      }
    })
});
```

I tried this. It works with the legacy reducer function to not warn/error on mutation, however, it didn't work with the slice reducer.

Either way, state mutations are bad and incorrect behavior in React. I'm surprised by this in such an established library.

There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/issues/43) regarding this library's props mutation with some decent discussion.

It's up to you if you want to do this in Redux, and there's the workaround I've described above. Using local component state seems to be a little easier though.

Here's the running codesandbox demo I created to test your code.

[image: Edit how-to-use-redux-with-react-plotly-js]

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Are you saying that the reason the plot doesn't render is because the ``Plot`` component may mutate it's ``layout`` (according to the GitHub page) and ``reduxjs-toolkit`` guards against mutating the state?

Comment: Aren't you always mutating the redux state anytime it is updated, so why would ``reduxjs-toolkit`` guard against that?

Comment: @Simon1 I'm saying the reason using the redux-toolkit for the plot state doesn't work is because it guards state mutations. In React we don't, or shouldn't, ever mutate state or props. This includes using redux. Old redux uses an [immutable state update pattern](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns), and in redux-toolkit we are using mutable updates on a draft copy of the state which then get applied in an immutable way. That's why I was a bit surprised to find this plot library mutating the props passed to it.

Comment: @Simon1 I suspect if you updated your React state version to create a copy of the `layout` state and then froze it with [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to be passed as props that it also would not work since those other properties wouldn't be injected.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I found to work (although not ideal) is to use [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) to create a deep copy of `layout` that is managed by redux, and then supply that deep copy to the `Plot` component.

```
export default function PlotReduxState() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { layout } = useSelector((state) => state.plot);
  const { width, ref } = useResizeDetector();

  // Create a deep copy of layout and supply
  // to the Plot component
  const layout2 = structuredClone(layout);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Edit title"
        onChange={(event) => dispatch(updateTitle(event.target.value))}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Edit x-axis title"
        onChange={(event) => dispatch(updateXLabel(event.target.value))}
      />
      <Plot layout={{ width, ...layout2 }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```